# RenderBox was not laid out error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im working on flutter where fetching data from api. I want to show shimmer loader while data is loading but its giving "**Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#c8a3f relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT**". Please find the below code for your reference and help to resolve.

Thanks in advance

```
class HomepageSectionView extends StatelessWidget {
const HomepageSectionView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Consumer<HomepageSectionProvider>(
  builder: (context, homepageSectionProvider, child) {
    return homepageSectionProvider.homepageSectionList.isNotEmpty
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: homepageSectionProvider.homepageSectionList.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL,
                        20,
                        Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL,
                        Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          homepageSectionProvider
                              .homepageSectionList[index].title
                              .toString(),
                          style: amberSemibold,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: homepageSectionProvider
                            .homepageSectionList[index]
                            .subSections!
                            .isNotEmpty
                        ? const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 150)
                        : const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: homepageSectionProvider
                                    .homepageSectionList[index]
                                    .subSections!
                                    .length >
                                10
                            ? 10
                            : homepageSectionProvider
                                .homepageSectionList[index]
                                .subSections!
                                .length,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      ProductListByHomepageSection(
                                        sectionId: homepageSectionProvider
                                            .homepageSectionList[index]
                                            .subSections![i]
                                            .id
                                            .toString(),
                                        sectionTitle:
                                            homepageSectionProvider
                                                .homepageSectionList[index]
                                                .subSections![i]
                                                .title
                                                .toString(),
                                      )));
                            },
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                      1.5) -
                                  5,
                              child: Card(
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 300,
                                  height: 100,
                                  child: Stack(children: [
                                    Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                          placeholder: Images.placeholder,
                                          image: homepageSectionProvider
                                              .homepageSectionList[index]
                                              .subSections![i]
                                              .banner,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        )),
                                    Container(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        height: 70,
                                        width: 120,
                                        child: DecoratedBox(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  const BorderRadius.all(
                                                      Radius.circular(5)),
                                              color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                                      232, 115, 22, 1)
                                                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
                                          child: Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: [
                                              Text(
                                                homepageSectionProvider
                                                    .homepageSectionList[
                                                        index]
                                                    .subSections![i]
                                                    .title,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 18,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold,
                                                    color: Colors.white),
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                homepageSectionProvider
                                                    .homepageSectionList[
                                                        index]
                                                    .subSections![i]
                                                    .bannerText!,
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 14,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                        FontWeight.bold,
                                                    color:
                                                        Colors.blueAccent),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              );
            })
        : HomepageSectionShimmer(isHomeScreen: true);
   },
   );
  }
  }

class HomepageSectionShimmer extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isHomeScreen;
 const HomepageSectionShimmer({Key? key, required this.isHomeScreen})
  : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: isHomeScreen ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
  itemCount: 2,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      width: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: ColorResources.WHITE,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                spreadRadius: 1,
                blurRadius: 5)
          ]),
      child: Shimmer.fromColors(
        baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
        highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
        enabled: Provider.of<HomepageSectionProvider>(context)
            .homepageSectionList
            .isEmpty,
        child:
            Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_LARGE),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: ColorResources.ICON_BG,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(height: 20, color: ColorResources.WHITE),
                    const SizedBox(
                        height: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL),
                    Row(children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                  height: 20,
                                  width: 50,
                                  color: ColorResources.WHITE),
                            ]),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          height: 10,
                          width: 50,
                          color: ColorResources.WHITE),
                      const Icon(Icons.star,
                          color: Colors.orange, size: 15),
                    ]),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your listview into Expanded() widget which will allow to take all available space

Comment: Tried this but not working

Comment: Axis.hortizaontal need proper space which means if you want to use Axis.hortizaontal you need to give proper height so you can wrap either with container() or sizeBox() with some height

Comment: Wrapping listview with container resolved the issue. Thanks